# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

full Login.js

```js
'use strict'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

class login extends Component{
 static navigationOptions = {
   title: 'Login'
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.contenedor} >
          <Text style={styles.title}>La App chula</Text>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.boton} onPress={(this.onLogin.bind(this))}>
            <Text style={styles.letra}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }

  onLogin = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Acceso',
      'Te has logueado en el sistema',
      [
        {text: 'Aceptar',
        onPress:(() => this.prop.navigation.navigate('Dashboard'))},
        {text: 'Cancelar',
        onPress:(this.cancelar.bind(this))}
      ]
    )
  }
  cancelar(){
    console.log(this.props)
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contenedor:{
  flex: 1,
  /*justifyContent: 'center', /*Alineado Horizontalmente */
  alignItems: 'center', /*Alineado Vertical*/
  },
  boton:{
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 300,
    height: 30,
    marginTop: 60,
    marginBottom: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  letra:{
    color: 'white',
  },
  title:{
    fontSize: 25,
    marginTop: 100,
  },
});

module.exports = login
```

Hi I'm trying to learn React Native; I'm making an app native in IOS and i had this issue in Login.js when i was programming the navigator, anyone can help me? this is my code:
 index.ios.js:
Configuration of StackNavigator

```js
const IndexApp = StackNavigator({
    Login: {screen: Login},
    Dashboard: {screen: Dashboard}
```

in Login.js we have an alert; when you accept it takes you to the dashboard, we have first a navigationOptions in the login Component, we have other similar in Dashboard Component:

```js
class login extends Component{
 static navigationOptions = {
   title: 'Login'
 }
```

in the same file:

```js
onLogin(){
    Alert.alert(
      'Acceso',
      'Te has logueado en el sistema',
      [
        {text: 'Aceptar',
        onPress:() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')},
        {text: 'Cancelar',
        onPress:(this.cancelar.bind(this))}
      ]
    )
  }
```

Comment: Inside of `Login.js`, bind `onLogin()` within the constructor. Alternatively, you can use an arrow function `onLogin = () => {}`. You're receiving this error because `this` is `undefined` in React, unless you `bind()` your functions. Binding changes the context of `this`.

Comment: I have a function in that bind that console.log cancelar, i change onLogin using an arrow function within the constructor, and still undefined

Comment: Could you please post your whole `Login.js` file in the question?

Comment: Sure, i edited the post and put the whole code there

Comment: Change `onPress:(() => this.prop.navigation.navigate('Dashboard'))},` to `onPress:(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard'))},` You're referencing `prop` instead of `props`.

Comment: still Undefined